# More likely to choose certain elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm writing some code, but figured this was more of a mathematical question. I'm creating a fictional language, and decided to make a word generator. It works by randomly selecting building blocks for words and then combining them.

My issue is that I want some of these building blocks to have a greater probability of being selected than others. If I store a bunch of them in an array, they will all have an equally likely chance of being selected. What mathematics would I need to do in order to create a greater likelihood of choosing certain elements?

Comment: Include multiple identical letters in your array in proportion to the frequency you wish each to occur.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is you take a list $a_0,\dots,a_{n - 1}$ of building blocks and give them weights $p_0,\dots,p_{n - 1}$ where a larger value of $p_i$ means that $a_i$ is more likely to be chosen. Let us say for example that $p_0,\dots,p_{n - 1}$ are integers.

Now let $P = p_0 + \dots + p_{n - 1}$ and choose a random integer between $1$ and $P$. If that integer lies between $p_0 + \dots + p_{i - 1} + 1$ and $p_0 + \dots + p_i$ then take $a_i$. This range has size $p_i$ so the probability of choosing $a_i$ is therefore $p_i/P$.

You might implement it like so:

```
a[] = an array of size n
p[] = an array of size n
P = sum of p[0] through p[n - 1]

let t = RandInt(1, P)
let i = 0
while t > 0 :
   t = t - p[i]
   i = i + 1

when the while loop closes, choose a[i - 1]
```

So for example: $p_0 = 3$ and $p_1 = 1$ and $p_2 = 4$ and $P = 8$

- if $t = 2$ then after one pass through the while loop $t = -1$ and $i = 1$ and we take $a_{i - 1} = a_0$
- if $t = 4$ then after the first pass $t = 1$ and $i = 1$; after the second pass $t = 0$ and $i = 2$ and we take $a_{i - 1} = a_1$
- if $t = 6$ then after the first pass $t = 3$ and $i = 1$; after the second $t = 2$ and $i = 2$; after the third $t = -2$ and $i = 3$ and we take $a_{i - 1} = a_2$

Note that $t = 1, 2, 3$ will give you $a_0$; $t = 4$ will give you $a_1$ and $t = 5, 6, 7, 8$ will give you $a_2$.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to draw elements with different probabilities, so I'd actually say that's an implementation question. You just need to decide what probability you want for each of them. One way is to draw a uniform number from zero to 1, carve the interval into segments whose lengths are the probabilities of the various words and then choose the word whose segment the rand number falls in. Doing this in a clean and efficient manner is a coding question of course (and I see as I was writing this another person gave a nice answer with a way to do this). A cruder way would be to simply put more instances of the more popular words in your array.

As to mathematics you might consider that in languages, it's not just that words have different probabilities than others but that certain words are likely to be next to each other. You may want to explore Markov chains and state space models and how they can be used to generate realistic text.